# PAM authentication + pgAdmin fails remotely, but locally works

Tags: postgresql, authentication, ssh, pgadmin, pam

I've been trying to configure postgresql with PAM on a Red hat server so that I can get remote access to the server via pgAdmin and use local (server) authentication with PAM.

I have edited the pg_hba.conf file and changed the appropriate line:

```
host postgres all 0.0.0.0/0 md5
```

and added this one:

```
host    pam_testing       all  0.0.0.0/0   pam    pamservice=postgresql95
```

Moreover I created database user with the same username as I use to log in with putty (no password, simply create user xxx)

When I try to log in remotely with pgAdmin to postgres database (using md5) with my database user everything works smoothly.

But When I try to connect (also remotely, with pgAdmin) to pam_testing database with my server username (to which I log in via ssh using putty) and give the password I get the following error:

> Error connecting to the server: FATAL: PAM authentication failed for
>   user XXX

BUT! When I log in locally to pam_testing while connected via putty it works! My system user gets logged in and authenticated without any problems. And it only happens for users, which I added to the database using create user.

I'm guessing it must be some kind of authentication issue (with the server maybe? It belongs to company and I don't know what other authentication methods it uses) but I'm not sure. Any ideas?

System: Red hat 6.8,
Postgresql: 9.5

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Do `systemctl | grep unix_chkpwd` and if you see lines like these

```
unix_chkpwd[13081]: check pass; user unknown
unix_chkpwd[13081]: password check failed for user (<username>)
```

then you've encountered the same problem I did.

To solve it you need to give `postgres` user read permissions to `/etc/shadow` file. You can do this via acl: `setfacl -m g:postgres:r /etc/shadow`, or by creating some group, giving it this permission and then adding `postgres` to it. Then do `systemctl restart postgresql.service`.

The underlying mechanics of authenticating with pam is described in [this post](https://java.net/projects/hudson/lists/users/archive/2009-03/message/367). The key moment is the following: `unix_chkpwd` runs under the uid of the process which wants to authenticate someone, so if it's not root (and `/etc/shadow` is used which I believe is the common case), it can't do its job.

Comment: Alternatively, if you're using e.g. ldap instead of /etc/shadow, you can provide a config in /etc/pam.d that doesn't include pam_unix.so